# Copy CD to ISO including bad sectors

Tags: iso-image, bad-sectors, cd, disc

I am currently trying to copy a Sims2 Game CD to ISO as most CD Disk-trays are now retired and aren't common on newer machines.

I've tried multiple disk tools but this disk has a purpose bad sector on it - from research I'm not even sure there is any data on this.

If anyone could help me out with this that would be great?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Get a USB CD drive. These work - I have one here.

Comment: I suggest you state what  method you used to try to do it and show a screenshot of the error you got

Comment: For those CDs, if I remember correctly, you would need to use special software. Yes, it's a "bad sector" or, more accurately, a format that violates the standard for CD-ROMs and a copy protection. Back in the day there were an handful of special programs designed to overcome the copy protection. So, as suggested above, better to get a cheap USB drive and keep using the original CDs until they break for good.

Comment: @John Thank you for recommending this!